# Is there any way to copy latest file and folder from source (sort the new create files and folder) by using c#?

Tags: c#

[Example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yllCO.png)

I want to save the files by clicking checbox and button, but the problem is I want to save recent files and folder only. Is there any way to sort the target's date, before copy the folder?

## Here is the entire code:

```
namespace NewFunctionTesting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //variable
        int count = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++; //for button
            if (checkBox1.Checked == true && count == 1) //first testing
            {
                //copy latest 1
                string ProductionImage = @"C:\Users\IM10\Documents\Image";
                string NewProductionImage = @"C:\Users\IM10\Documents\NewImage";
                Copy(ProductionImage, NewProductionImage);

                string ProductionIImageValue = @"C:\Users\IM10\Documents\Value";
                string NewProductionIImageValue = @"C:\Users\IM10\Documents\NewValue";
                Copy(ProductionIImageValue, NewProductionIImageValue);
            }
            else if (checkBox1.Checked == true && count == 2) //second testing
            {
                //copy latest 2
                string ProductionImage = @"C:\Users\IM10\Documents\Image";
                string NewProductionImage = @"C:\Users\IM10\Documents\NewImage";
                Copy(ProductionImage, NewProductionImage);

                string ProductionIImageValue = @"C:\Users\IM10\Documents\Value";
                string NewProductionIImageValue = @"C:\Users\IM10\Documents\NewValue";
                Copy(ProductionIImageValue, NewProductionIImageValue);
            }
            else if (checkBox1.Checked == true && count >= 3) //third testing
            {
                //uncheck the checkbox
                checkBox1.Checked = false;
                count = 0;

                //copy latest 3
                string ProductionImage = @"C:\Users\IM10\Documents\Image";
                string NewProductionImage = @"C:\Users\IM10\Documents\NewImage";
                Copy(ProductionImage, NewProductionImage);

                string ProductionIImageValue = @"C:\Users\IM10\Documents\Value";
                string NewProductionIImageValue = @"C:\Users\IM10\Documents\NewValue";
                Copy(ProductionIImageValue, NewProductionIImageValue);
            }
            else if (checkBox1.Checked == false) 
            {
                count = 0;
            }
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //empty
        }

        public static void Copy(string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory)
        {
            var diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
            var diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);

            CopyAll(diSource, diTarget);
        }

        public static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);

            // Copy each file into the new directory
            foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
            {
                fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, fi.Name), true);
            }

            // Copy each subdirectory using recursion (i need to sort the folder date)
            foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories().OrderBy(fi => fi.LastWriteTime).ToList())
            {
                    DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
                        target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
                    CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
            }
        }

        public static FileInfo GetNewestFile(DirectoryInfo directory)
        {
            return directory.GetFiles()
                .Union(directory.GetDirectories().Select(d => GetNewestFile(d)))
                .OrderByDescending(f => (f == null ? DateTime.MinValue : f.LastWriteTime))
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What will be the difference if you sort the files before copying? The effect will be the same at the end, or?

Comment: This code will copy all the files and folder to a new directory, but I want something that is copy the latest one (latest creation). So I think I might need a sort function in order to copy certain folder only. For example, in a directory there are many folders created and I want to copy the latest folder which include files (latest creation) into new location.

Comment: ```Directory.GetCreationTime(String)```